# Clementine with GStreamer can't play OGG files

Tags: fedora, gstreamer, ogg, clementine

Starting recently, about 2-3 weeks ago, I believe after some update, Clementine stopped playing OGG files. All other formats that I have play without any issues. At the same time VLC can play these same OGG files.

When it fails, Clementine pops an error window with the following message only: **Internal data stream error.**

[image: Internal data stream error]

At the same time, this error message gets printed to the terminal:

```
(clementine:647736): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:27:26.111: gst_pad_get_range_unchecked: assertion '!*buffer || res_buf == *buffer' failed

(clementine:647736): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:27:26.111: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'GST_MINI_OBJECT_REFCOUNT_VALUE (mini_object) > 0' failed
11:27:26.186 WARN  unknown                          QTimeLine::start: already running 
11:27:26.691 WARN  unknown                          QTimeLine::start: already running 
11:27:26.691 WARN  unknown                          QTimeLine::start: already running 
11:27:26.695 WARN  unknown                          QTimeLine::start: already running
```

Version info:

- Fedora 33 5.9.11-200.fc33.x86_64
- clementine.x86_64: 1.4.0-3.rc1.20200617gitedb8c3b.fc33.1
- gstreamer1.x86_64: 1.18.2-1.fc33
- gstreamer1-libav.x86_64: 1.18.1-1.fc33
- gstreamer1-plugin-openh264.x86_64: 1.16.2-2.fc33
- gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free.x86_64: 1.18.2-1.fc33
- gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-extras.x86_64: 1.18.2-1.fc33
- gstreamer1-plugins-base.x86_64: 1.18.2-1.fc33
- gstreamer1-plugins-good.x86_64: 1.18.2-1.fc33
- gstreamer1-plugins-good-gtk.x86_64: 1.18.2-1.fc33
- gstreamer1-plugins-good-qt.x86_64: 1.18.2-1.fc33
- gstreamer1-plugins-ugly.x86_64: 1.18.1-1.fc33
- gstreamer1-plugins-ugly-free.x86_64: 1.18.2-1.fc33

Any idea on what caused it and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was having the same problem, or at least the same symptoms, on Ubuntu 20.10.  It was affecting Clementine and gst-play-1.0 from the command line in the same way.  Problem started after upgrading from 20.04.  In my case it only affected a few albums in my collection out of ~680 ogg files.  Turns out it was a specific encoder that is likely problematic.  When running ogginfo on these files it would show the Vendor string as such:

Vendor: Xiphophorus libVorbis I 20010813 (1.0 rc2)

and an error like this:

WARNING: Hole in data (128 bytes) found at approximate offset 5265129 bytes. Corrupted Ogg.

So it could be that you are also experiencing a bug in an older encoder which previous versions of GStreamer ignored, but now have problems with.

I found that re-encoding the files with ffmpeg fixed the issue:
`ffmpeg -i file.ogg -acodec copy newfile.ogg`

I also posted basically the same details on the bug report you opened here:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/-/issues/848

Answer (score 0):

Element Green. thank you for posting your answer, I joined stackexchange specially to post this thank you and can't upvote or comment since I'm new.

I edited the ID3 tags on most of my music and all the .ogg based files started having problems with "Internal data stream" errors on both Clementine and Rhythmbox audio players. Files played fine via VLC.

I didn't relate the problem to editing the tags at the time. The reference in the gstreamer bug indicates the problem may be due to ID3 tags.

Running `ogginfo` on the problem files reported "Negative or zero granulepos (0) on Vorbis stream outside of headers. This file was created by a buggy encoder"

ogginfo is in Vorbis-tools package for anyone new like myself and trying to find it.

Running `ffmpeg -i file.ogg -acodec copy newfile.ogg` on all the problem files cleaned them up again and all working now.